# How to change a Less value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, less

I am creating a website with Less. This is my first time using LESS and I need to change the value of a Less variable with jQuery on page load. For example, from `@black: #000` to `@black: #ccc;`.

I have used `less.modifyVars({'@black': '#ccc'});`

It works fine, but when the variable is changed, I have some errors:

```
GET localhost/img/zoom.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Some images and fonts don't show. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like i have a problem about path. I have a folder img, css, less and i have declared  a font-face:
@font-face { font-family: 'X';
  src: url('../fonts/x.eot');
src: url('../fonts/x.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/x.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/x.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/x.svg#Gil') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}. After i change the variables with modifyVars it could not find the path, how i must add the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer for my question. Example if you want to modify a LESS variable in jQuery you must add the following code:

```
<script>
   less.modifyVars({'@color': '#0074c8'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a known bug ... but should be fixed in less 1.4

See this link:
https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/1201

They say there is no easy workaround as it is not keeping file structure.